Gauge transformations of non-abelian Chern-Simons theory
In non-abelian Chern-Simons theory, the gauge field transform as $ A_i \rightarrow g^{-1}A_i g +ig^{-1}\partial_i g$, where $g$ is the element of gauge group, while  the action itself transform as
$$
S_{cs}\rightarrow S_{cs} + \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int d^3x\; (\epsilon^{ijk}\partial_jtr(\partial_ig\,g^{-1}A_k)-\frac{1}{3}\epsilon^{ijk}tr(g^{-1}\partial_igg^{-1}\partial_jgg^{-1}\partial_kg))
$$
However when i derive this transformation, i found a term
$$
\epsilon^{ijk}tr(gA_iA_j\partial_kg^{-1})
$$
This term is clearly doesn't appear in the final transformation. How does this term vanishes?

It doesn't vanish. You made a mistake.

The term does appear in intermediate calculations, but cancels out in the final result.

The CS action is
$$
S_{CS}[A] = k \int \text{Tr}[ A F - \frac{1}{3} A^3 ] , \qquad F = d A + A^2 . 
$$
Under gauge transformations
$$
A \to A' = g^{-1} (A + h)g  , \qquad F \to F' = g^{-1} F g  ,  \qquad h = dg g^{-1} . 
$$
Note that $dh=h^2$. We then have
\begin{align}
S_{CS}[A'] &= k \int \text{Tr}[ (A+h) F - \frac{1}{3} (A+h)^3 ] \\
&=  k \int \text{Tr}[ A F + h F - \frac{1}{3} ( A^3 + 3 A^2 h + 3 A h^2 + h^3 )  ] \\
&=  k \int \text{Tr}[ A F + h F - \frac{1}{3} A^3 - A^2 h - A h^2 -  \frac{1}{3} h^3 ] \\
&=  S_{CS}[A] + k \int d \, \text{Tr}[ A h ]   - \frac{1}{3} k \int \text{Tr} [ h^3 ]
\end{align}
